# How do I reload a page and maintain the scroll position using a GET request?

Tags: javascript, python, django, http

I'm using Django and have the following view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process form
            return HttpResponse('''see below''')
    # The rest of the view...
```

#### Problem:

What I'm trying to do is to reload the page while staying in the same scroll position. I've tried to put a couple things in the `'''see below'''` area of the `HttpResponse`:

#### Attempt 1:

```
return HttpResponse('<script>window.location.href = window.location.href</script>')
```

This refreshes the whole page, and the scroll position is lost.

#### Attempt 2:

```
return HttpResponse('<script>document.location.reload(true)</script>')
```

This theoretically should work (and works if I just type it into the browser console), but since it's within a Django form with a POST request, the POST request is resubmitted, resulting in an infinite loop of POST requests.

Note: At least that is what I think is happening. Here is the command prompt output (only shows the first few lines):

```
[12/Sep/2018 20:05:53] "GET /tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10654
[12/Sep/2018 20:05:54] "POST /tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 200 47
[12/Sep/2018 20:05:54] "POST /tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 200 47
[12/Sep/2018 20:05:54] "POST /tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 200 47
```

#### Question

Is there a way to BOTH reload the page at the correct scroll position AND use a GET request rather than a POST request?

Comment: attempt 2 `document.location.reload()` stores the location, hence will reload to same position

Comment: I know the question is a semi server-side question but I'd just go for full javascript in this one. You can add an event listener to update the scroll location cookie and then use `Element.scrollIntoView` when the page is first loaded.

Comment: @SubSul I know, but it has other problems (see post).

Comment: @IşıkKaplan Thanks, I'll try that!